# Type-safety in C

Tags: c, type-safety

Is there a way to make C a little more aware of types and assure type-safety?
Consider this:

```
typedef unsigned cent_t;
typedef unsigned dollar_t;

#define DOLLAR_2_CENT(dollar)       ((cent_t)(100*(dollar)))

void calc(cent_t amount) {
    // expecting 'amount' to semantically represents cents...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    dollar_t amount = 50;
    calc(DOLLAR_2_CENT(amount));  // ok
    calc(amount);                 // raise warning
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to make the above code at-least raise warning by the gcc?
I know I can use C-structs to wrap `unsigned`s and achieve the desired result, I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way to do it.
Can it be a little more than that?

Comment: Make `cent_t` and `dollar_t` a struct, with just one member?

Comment: C is not really a type-safe language. The simplest way to *emulate* type-safety is to use structures.

Comment: Declare all your functions properly before use (complete list of function arguments, etc).   Pass structs rather than basic types (or typedefs of basic types).   Prefer inline functions over macros.   Turn up warning levels on your compiler.

Comment: I believe [splint](http://www.splint.org/) can check for this. There may be other compilers or static analysis tools that can as well.

Comment: Declaring money to use an unsigned type is not a great idea. It may give you a false sense of wealth when you overspend.

Comment: Note that compiling the file as C++ gives you some extra type-safety. Not really a good solution, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a static analysis tool in your build process to achieve this.

For example, if you run PCLint on your code, it gives this output:

```
  [Warning 632] Assignment to strong type 'cent_t' in context: arg. no. 1
  [Warning 633] Assignment from a strong type 'dollar_t' in context: arg. no. 1
```

http://www.gimpel.com/html/strong.htm

Comment: Good! I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a free alternative? :(

Comment: I am accepting this answer, because after further research, it seems like this is exactly what I was looking for: A static analysis tool that will warn me/raise error whenever I make types errors.

Answer (score 31):

The problem is that C doesn't treat your two typedefs as distinctive types, because they are both type `unsigned`.

There are various tricks to dodge this. One thing would be to change your types to enums. Good compilers will enforce stronger typing warnings on implicit conversions to/from a certain enum type to any other type.

Even if you don't have a good compiler, with enums you could do this:

```
typedef enum { FOO_CENT  } cent_t;
typedef enum { FOO_DOLLAR} dollar_t;

#define DOLLAR_2_CENT(dollar)       ((cent_t)(100*(dollar)))

void calc(cent_t amount) {
    // expecting 'amount' to semantically represents cents...
}

#define type_safe_calc(amount) _Generic(amount, cent_t: calc(amount))

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    dollar_t amount = 50;
    type_safe_calc(DOLLAR_2_CENT(amount));  // ok
    type_safe_calc(amount);         // raise warning

    return 0;
}
```

---

A more conventional/traditional trick is to use a generic struct wrapper, where you use a "ticket" enum to mark the type. Example:

```
typedef struct
{
  type_t type;
  void*  data;
} wrapper_t;

...

cent_t my_2_cents;
wrapper_t wrapper = {CENT_T, &my_2_cents};

...

switch(wrapper.type)
{
  case CENT_T: calc(wrapper.data)
  ...
}
```

The advantage is that it works with any C version. Disadvantage is code and memory overhead, and that it only allows run-time checks.

Comment: Are the `FOO_CENT` and `FOO_DOLLAR` just dummy values?

Comment: Structs are out of the question (like you said, there are memory and code penalties, and I can't afford that...)

Comment: @so.very.tired Yeah it is just nonsense dummies. You can use an enum to store any integer values, though how large the enum actually is depends on the compiler.

Comment: Your first example could be perfect for me, but are you sure it should raise warning? I tried to compile it with `gcc -Wall` but the compiler didn't show any warnings...

Comment: @so.very.tired No it should raise a compiler error `error: '_Generic' selector of type 'enum <anonymous>' is not compatible with any association|
`. You must be doing something very wrong. Make sure to use at least a semi-modern version of gcc that has some amount of C11 support.

Comment: Come to think of it, to get more explicit compiler errors you should probably do `typedef enum dollar_t { FOO_DOLLAR} dollar_t;` with an enum tag, which gives `error: '_Generic' selector of type 'enum dollar_t'`

Comment: There are some portability issues with `enum` hack that may have to be considered. Some compilers will throw warnings if you try to assign `int` to an `enum` type, like in `dollar_t amount = 50;`.

Comment: @user694733 If they do, then that's great! Because it means they will likely also give warnings for the different enum incompatibilities. Your example should have been written as `dollar_t amount = (dollar_t)50;` because `50` is of type `int` and not `dollar_t`. The only portability issues here is: 1) enum variables have implementation-defined size, so they aren't necessarily the same size as an `int` and 2) enum variables are signed type, where the original type was unsigned.

Comment: @so.very.tired How exactly do you expect there to be memory and code penalties for a `struct cents { unsigned count; }`?  A two-element struct that stores the type in a runtime field can have penalties; I would be surprised if a struct containing just a single unsigned value has any.

Comment: @Yakk will one-member-struct containing unsigned behave exactly like unsigned? both syntactically and semantically? **edit** Well, you are right. no memory overhead. Still, the syntax would have to be changed dramatically.

Comment: Where did `_Generic` come from?

Answer (score 10):

Aliasing has a very specific narrow meaning in C, and it's not what you have in mind. You may want to say "typedefing".

And the answer is no, you can't. Not in an elegant way at any rate. You can use a struct for each numeric type, and a separate set of functions to do arithmetic with each one. Except when it comes to multiplication, you are out of luck. In order to multiply feet by pounds, you need a third type. You also need types for feet squared, feet cubed, seconds to the power of minus two and an infinite number of other types.

If this is what you are after, C is not the right language.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: Here an alternative that works even in C89, in case your compiler doesn't support `_Generic` selector's (a lot of compilers don't and often you're stuck with what's installed on your machine).

You can use macros to simplify the use of `struct` wrappers.

```
#define NEWTYPE(nty,oty) typedef struct { oty v; } nty
#define FROM_NT(ntv)       ((ntv).v)
#define TO_NT(nty,val)     ((nty){(val)})  /* or better ((nty){ .v=(val)}) if C99 */


NEWTYPE(cent_t, unsigned);
NEWTYPE(dollar_t, unsigned);

#define DOLLAR_2_CENT(dollar)       (TO_NT(cent_t, 100*FROM_NT(dollar)))

void calc(cent_t amount) {
     // expecting 'amount' to semantically represents cents...
}  

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    dollar_t amount = TO_NT(dollar_t, 50);  // or alternatively {50};
    calc(DOLLAR_2_CENT(amount));  // ok
    calc(amount);                 // raise warning
    return 0;
}
```

You get even stronger than a warning. Here is the compilation result with gcc 5.1

```
$ gcc -O3  -Wall Edit1.c
Edit1.c: In function ‘main’:
Edit1.c:17:10: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘calc’
     calc(amount);                 // raise warning
          ^
Edit1.c:10:6: note: expected ‘cent_t {aka struct }’ but argument is of type ‘dollar_t {aka struct }’
 void calc(cent_t amount);// {
```

and here the result with gcc 3.4

```
$ gcc -O3  -Wall Edit1.c
Edit1.c: In function 'main':
Edit1.c:17: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'calc'
```

Comment: C89 doesn't have designated initializers, third line of your example wouldn't compile.

Comment: Did you try this with `-std=c89`

Comment: Yes. it compiled without warning. May be I should have tried `-pedantic`.

Comment: Is `(TO_NT (cent_t, 100 * FROM_NT (dollar)))` really preferable to `( (cent_t) { 100 * (dollar).v } )`?

Comment: Not really, but that's what one has to do to use `struct` container to have strong type check in C. Is it that useful in practice? I don't think it is, but that's what the OP wanted to do. So I proposed an alternative to the accepted answer, that's all. As always *Caveat emptor*.

Answer (score 0):

C is not type safe, if you want type safe you have to choose another language, there is no workaround of it, and try to do a "type safe C" is like try to program in another language. And C is good as it is, because in ASM/machine code/cpu instructions there is no type safety construct, and C is quite close to it, but in that perspective is a high level language.

So also back at yuor example, rather than having 2 unsigned, it would be enough to have a fixed point number that you can simply emulate with `* 100` so basically $1.00 is stored in your number as 100.

Also not sure if unsigned could be striclty the right choice.

Furthermore if you want a more fancy not required high-level construct you can use a struct of 2 values for the amount and the cents. wasting twice the memory requirement for no real more information. But i will just suggest that you should **go with a fixed point type**

Finally going more on your question: u**se the compiler and enable all the warnings and force them as error**. And yes as other wrote already get also the help of some static analysis tools.

But *what are you looking for is not the C language.*

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: @julaine it answer that is not possible to do type safety in C, then elaborates on why and if a user want type safety feature in a programming language should not use C.

not sure what the point of your question. is C type safe? simply No. there is no way to hack a programming language to have that feature. that is a new programming language.